# Magento 1 LiteMage not working

Tags: magento-1.9, litespeed

> LiteMage Error(Admin): Your installation of LiteSpeed Web Server does
>   not have LiteMage Cache enabled. Please make sure your LiteSpeed
>   license includes the LiteMage cache module, and LiteMage is turned on
>   in the .htaccess file in the root directory of your Magento
>   installation.

Magento Version: 1.9.4

I talked to the place where I bought the server service, they said they made the settings related to Litespeed

does not work even though I do the settings on the website

```
<IfModule Litespeed> 
 LiteMage on 
 </IfModule>
```

I added the above code

Photos Admin: http://prntscr.com/n706pl

Answer (score 0):

You have to check with your license provider whether the LiteMage addon for LiteSpeed Web Server is actually a part of the license you have.

There are 4 options for caching (assuming it's the "new" license type):

- LSCache Standard
- LiteMage Starter + LSCache
- LiteMage Standard + LSCache
- LiteMage Unlimited + LSCache

You have to ensure that you have at least "LiteMage Starter + LSCache" on your LiteSpeed Web Server license, else the LiteMage Cache won't be enabled on the server.

If your server license do have "LiteMage Starter + LSCache", then ensure that LiteMage is turned on in `.htaccess` like following:

```
 <IfModule Litespeed> 
 LiteMage on 
 </IfModule>
```